# Proving $\sum_{k\geq1}\mathbb{E}[X^2\chi_{k-1\leq |X|<k}]\sum_{n\geq k}\frac1{n^2}\leq2\sum_{k\geq1}\mathbb{E}[X^2\chi_{k-1\leq|X|<k}]\frac1k$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, inequality

I would like to prove
$$\sum_{k \geq 1}\mathbb{E}[X^2 \chi_{k-1 \leq |X| < k}] \sum_{n \geq k}\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 2\sum_{k \geq 1}\mathbb{E}[X^2 \chi_{k-1 \leq |X| < k}] \frac 1 k$$

Is it true that $$\sum_{n \geq k}\frac{1}{n^2} \leq \frac 2 k$$? If no, how can I prove the first inequality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_j^{j+1}\frac  1 {x^{2}} dx \geq \frac  1 {(j+1)^{2}}$. Suming over $j$ this gives $\frac 1 k=\int_k^{\infty} \frac 1 {x^{2}}dx \geq \sum\limits_{n=k+1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^{2}}$. Now the proof reduces to $\frac  1 {k^{2}}+ \frac 1 k \leq \frac  2 k$ which is true.